# Prevent javascript from auto escaping & character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I am seeing `&amp;` in my textbox but I only want `&`. I think it is something to do with the way browser interpret javascript `.innerHTML`.
The text with `&` must pass through div. For some reason, I can't directly assign value to the text box.

HTML Code

```
<div id='div'></div>
<input id='textbox' type='text' />
```

Javascript Code

```
var str = 'this & char';
$('#div').append("<div>" + str + "</div>");
$('#textbox').val($('#div').html());
```

Actual HTML output

```
<div>this &amp; char</div>
```

and user sees `this &amp; char` in textbox.

Desire HTML output

```
<div>this & char</div>
```

and user sees `this & char` in textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `.html()` which is the reason the `&` gets translated to `&amp;`. Since it's an input, it must be in plain text and hence, when you write `&amp;` in an input field, it's displayed as a text.

```
$('#textbox').val($('#div').text());
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't directly write to the textbox. The value must pass through div.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). `html()` treats the string as HTML, `text()` treats the content as text.

```js
var str = 'this & char';
$('#div').append("<div>" + str + "</div>");
$('#textbox').val($('#div').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'></div>
<input id='textbox' type='text' />
```